# How to change Opacity Property of items in listview item template by visual state manager?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, visualstatemanager

I am trying to get a `listview` to display a list of items made up of `textblocks` and `rectangles`.

When the `listview` item is clicked I would like to change the opacity property of textblocks.

Why do I get an error when I click it?

My `listview`:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmp}" x:Name="lstviewtest1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}">
        <ItemsControl/>
</ListView>
```

And my resource:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rt1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rt2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                 .....
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmp" >
    <Grid Width="400" Height="190">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="145"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       ...
        <Rectangle x:Name="rt1" Margin="17,0,27,0" Opacity="0.7" Fill="LightBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="rt2" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="8" Fill="LightGreen"  />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Margin="17,11,0,0" Opacity="0.7" FontSize="28" FontFamily="Candara" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Daily"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Margin="17,14.5,0,0" Opacity="0.7"  FontSize="23" FontFamily="Candara"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Balance"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt3" Margin="17,58,0,0" Opacity="0.7"  FontSize="23" FontFamily="Candara" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Balance"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt4" Margin="17,101.5,0,0" Opacity="0.7"  FontSize="23" FontFamily="Candara" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Balance"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt5" Margin="0,14.5,27,0" Opacity="0.7"  FontSize="23" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="+2,372.73"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt6" Margin="0,58,27,0" Opacity="0.7"  FontSize="23" FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="#FFEC6843" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="-22,462.73"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt7" Margin="0,101.5,27,0" Opacity="0.7"   FontSize="23" FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="#FF5C9FAE" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="+2,372.73"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I fixed some typo's and some of the formatting.

Comment: You have `<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>` however `TiltContainer` is not defined.

Comment: @JustinXL how to defined `Tiltcontainer` ?

Comment: @JustinXL I do not understand the difference between `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`. and my My problem is that I can not change some of the properties of some not all elements within the itemtemplate in different state. Please help me